# WCF Windows Service Error: The socket connection has been disposed

Tags: c#, wcf, sockets, windows-services

I have 2 WCF services that are both installed locally on the same Windows Service. The 2 WCF services make calls to the same database and use Net TCP Binding.

Side Note: I made 2 services instead of 1 because the service had too many methods and as a result, the XML file was too large and I couldn't add the service reference to the consumer app. Also, it's more readable this way.

On the client app, I've added a service reference to both WCF services. To use the services, I extended the CommunicationObject so it has a "Using()" method: see the code below.

**Communication Object Extension for .Using() Method**

```
public static class CommunicationObjectExtensions
{
    public static void Using<T>(this T client, Action<T> work)
        where T : ICommunicationObject
    {
        try
        {
            // make sure client is open
            //client.Open(); // didn't work                
            work(client);
        }
        catch (CommunicationException e)
        {
            client.Abort();
            throw;
        }
        catch (TimeoutException e)
        {
            client.Abort();
            throw;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            client.Abort();
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            client.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

**Service Calls**

```
new ServiceClientA().Using(client =>
    {
        var someObjectA = client.GetSomeObjectA();
    });
new ServiceClientB().Using(client =>
    {
        var someObjectB = client.GetSomeObjectB();
    });
```

I get the "The socket connection has been disposed" error when ServiceClientB's method actually has data to return (versus an empty list) and returns (I'm able to debug and go through the entire service call).

I don't run into this problem when using the other WCF services that point to different databases.

Anyone have any ideas what's going on?

**Update**

Ok turns out it only happens with the method I'm calling (client.GetSomeObjectB()). The object it's returning is causing errors. Apparently this is because the object is too big, but it shouldn't be a problem (since I'm only returning 1 small object).

Comment: Why would you expect anything different?  "client" is clearly getting closed in the first Using statement in the finally block. How would it be expected to work when called in the second statement?

Comment: It should get re-opened in the 2nd using statement. For example, I can write multiple using statements for ServiceClientA and it works fine.

Comment: What is happening when you save ServiceClientA and ServiceClientB in variables?

Comment: ServiceClientA has state Created, then Closed. ServiceClientB has state Created, then throws a "The socket connection was aborted"  exception when I try to Use it.

Comment: How? All I see is a client.open getting commented out.

Comment: The client is automatically opened with the first method call.